# Computation of Brownian Motion Probabilities indexed at T and 2T

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

for a practice problem sheet I was asked to compute $\mathbb{P}(B_T>0, B_{2T} < 0)$ for $T>0$ and a Brownian Motion $B$.

I initially thought that since $B_T$ is independent of $B_{2T}$, and each $B_T$ is distributed $ \mathcal{N}(0, t)$, the computation would be:

$\mathbb{P}(B_T>0, B_{2T} < 0) = \mathbb{P}(B_T > 0)\mathbb{P}(B_{2T}<0) = \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$.

However, I was told that the answer is $\frac{1}{8}$.

What am I missing? What is another way of going about this problem?

Comment: $B_T$ is not independent of $B_{2T}$, though $B_T$ is independent of $B_{2T}-B_T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two events are not independent.  Here's one way to think about it: Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent normals with mean $0$ and variance $T$.  Then the pair $(B_T,B_{2T})$ is distributed like $(X,X+Y)$.  Then you are looking for $\mathbb{P}(X > 0 , X+ Y < 0)$.  Try plotting this event in the $xy$-plane and see what its probability is in this case.

Comment: How do I go about computing this though? And why are these events not independent? Isn't $B_s$ independent of $B_t$ for $s<t$?

Comment: That is not correct.  $B_s$ and $B_{t - s}$ are independent for $s < t$.  To see how to compute this event, try my hint: draw this event in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.